# Undeclared Identifier in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I've just started learning solidity and I tried to make a contract in which you are able to add names to Santa's naughty or nice list, and I want to be able to enter a name and I want the output to be whether the name is on the naughty or nice list or doesn't exist. Here I just tried to see if the inputed name is in the Naughty list and it was giving me the error message: Undeclared Identifier. I get this error in the place highlighted in the last function, thank you to anyone that helps.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

contract SantaList {

    struct NaughtyList{
        string badBoy;
        uint position;
    }
    struct NiceList{
        string goodBoy;
        uint position;
    }

    NaughtyList[] public badNames;
    NiceList[] public goodNames;

    uint internal nextPosition = 1;

    function AddToBadList(string memory badBoy) public{
        badNames.push(NaughtyList(badBoy, nextPosition));
        nextPosition++;
    }

    function AddToNiceList(string memory goodBoy) public{
        goodNames.push(NiceList(goodBoy, nextPosition));
        nextPosition++;
    }

    function GetNaughtyList() view public returns(NaughtyList[] memory){
        return badNames;
    }

    function GetNiceList() view public returns(NiceList[] memory){
        return goodNames;
    }

    function CheckList(string memory name) public {
        for(uint i = 0; i < badNames.length; i++){
            if(badNames[i].badBoy == **badBoy**){
                return **badBoy**;
                return " is on the naughty list";
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Variables can only be public or private , not internal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there's a name in the badNames

```
function CheckList(string memory name) public view returns (string memory) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < badNames.length; i++){
        if(badNames[i].badBoy == name){
            return string(abi.encodePacked(name, " is on the naughty list"));
        }
    }
    return string(abi.encodePacked(name, " is not on the naughty list"));
}
```